# ST_Within does not return true

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, gis, geospatial, postgis

I have some data imported from a GeoPackage by using the `ogr2ogr` tool. I assume the import operation goes without any glitches since `ST_IsValidReason()` returns `Valid Geometry` for the imported multi-polygons (the `geom` column).

```
nzstat=# \d sa2_2020
                                           Table "public.sa2_2020"
     Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                Default                
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 gid             | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('sa2_2020_gid_seq'::regclass)
 sa22018_v1_00   | character varying           |           |          | 
 sa22018_v1_name | character varying           |           |          | 
 land_area_sq_km | double precision            |           |          | 
 area_sq_km      | double precision            |           |          | 
 shape_length    | double precision            |           |          | 
 geom            | geometry(MultiPolygon,2193) |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "sa2_2020_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)
    "sa2_2020_geom_geom_idx" gist (geom)

nzstat=# select ST_IsValidReason(geom) from sa2_2020 where gid=4;
 st_isvalidreason 
------------------
 Valid Geometry
(1 row)

nzstat=# select ST_IsValidReason(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(174.77632, -41.28671), 2193));
 st_isvalidreason 
------------------
 Valid Geometry
(1 row)

nzstat=# select sa22018_v1_name from sa2_2020 where ST_Within(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(174.82726, -41.16671), 2193), geom);
 sa22018_v1_name 
-----------------
(0 rows)

nzstat=#
```

The coordinates I use for `ST_MakePoint()` are from another database which gives the `x` and `y` values in NZGD2000 coordinate system (SRID = 2193)

```
               full_address_ascii                | gd2000_xcoord | gd2000_ycoord        
-------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------------
 1 Willis Street, Wellington Central, Wellington |     174.77632 |     -41.28671
```

The coordinate should be in one of the multi-polygons but my query returns no results. Is there anything I am missing here?

I use PostGIS 3.2 with PostgeSQL 13.5.

Thanks

Comment: Setsrid just changes the metadata not the coordinates, you need to use st_transform instead

Comment: The x and y coordinates are already given in SRID 2193, do I still need to use ST_Transform()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EPSG:2193](https://epsg.io/2193) has coordinates in metres so it is unlikely that your values (174.82726, -41.16671) are in that projection, it is much more likely that they are in degrees (WGS84, EPGS:4326). So you need to transform your point to compare them to polygons in EPSG:2193, thus your SQL should be something like:

```
select sa22018_v1_name from sa2_2020 where ST_Within(ST_TRANSFORM(ST_MakePoint(174.82726, -41.16671), 2193), geom);
```

[`ST_SetSRID`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) only changes the metadata of the point (**setting** the CRS), to actually change the values of a point's coordinates you need to reproject the point (**transform** it from one projection to another) and so must use [`ST_Transform`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html).

Comment: Thanks...It appears the column names for my coordinates are misleading (they are gd2000_xcoord and gd2000_ycoord, which made me to think that the values are in NZGD2000. Using `ST_Transform()` worked fine. I had to set the SRID for `geom` as well (by using `ST_SetSRID()`)